# Mongoose with ElasticSearch in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using mongoDB in node.js with mongoose now I want to use ElasticSearch. Now can anyone please tell me would it be better to use [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic), an npm module for both mongoose and ElasticSearch, or should I install [ElasticSearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using mongoose, you should **use mongoosastic**.

Mongoosastic already depends on the ElasticSearch Module to perform ElasticSearch operations

Comment: Actually i was thinking that when if will use mongoosastic now first i will have to create a schema and inside it i will mention elastic field elements but dont you think it will take more time to index fields again and again as the request comes to the server rather then just index the elastic elements once and use them. like i can do using elasticsearch module. Actually i am not clear about elasticsearch thats why i am asking this but anyways thnx for suggesting mongoosastic...............:)

Comment: @bkan, I have tried using mongoosastic and can't make 'Populate' to work. Do you know how to use it properly? I tried everything the documentation tells me and still I can't make it work. Thank you.

Comment: @nycdanie this udemy tutorial uses it.
https://www.udemy.com/build-an-amazon-clone-nodejs-stripe-elasticsearch/

Comment: @IvorScott Thanks for this, but the guy who made this doesn't answer the same problem that is being encountered.

Comment: That seems to be the major problem of Mongoosastic. As of today, it still doesn't populate as the documentation claims.